# What's wrong with my Masonry (Tumblr)

Tags: jquery, configure, masonry

I have been playing around with Masonry on a Tumblr. For some reasons, I get a huge space on the second line. I guess I am missing something. not sure why.

[http://geedesign2.tumblr.com/](http://geedesign2.tumblr.com/#weblog) (bottom of the page)

Any experts around ?

Thanks you very much

Comment: Password protected? If your issue has been resolved, please can you add your answer / solution to help others.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I can see a few things:

Check the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , (index):1216

And if you take a look at your code:

```
$('#portfoliowrap').masonry({
    columnWidth: , 
    itemSelector: '.entry'
});

$('#portfoliowrap').masonry({
    singleMode: true, 
    columnWidth: , 
    itemSelector: '.entry'
});
```

As you can see, you are initializing Masonry twice and in both cases, you are missing the "columnWidth" value. So Masonry isn't even being initialized.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected this error. it stil does not seem to be working though